# BBC's Regular Expression Puzzle

Tags: crossword-clues

[image: BBC Regular Expression Puzzle]

Rather than use traditional hints, each square must be a match of the regular expression associated with the row or column.

[Source](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/5LCB3rN2dWLqsmGMy5KYtBf/puzzle-for-today)

Comment: If you enjoyed this puzzle, there are a crap-ton more like it [here](https://regexcrossword.com/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have so far solved about half of the "crossword" and it is clear that the answer is going to be

> YOUR BEST AND WISEST REFUGE FROM ALL TROUBLES IS IN YOUR SCIENCE - ADA LOVELACE.

[EDITED after finishing it to add:]

And it does turn out that the regex clues alone are enough to nail it down, though I briefly thought they wouldn't.

Not that there's any extra information in it, but:

> [image]

[EDITED some time afterwards because I noticed I'd omitted a word when I posted this originally. That was a typo rather than an actual error in what I thought the answer was. Now fixed, anyway.]

Comment: I have no idea what the the hell those characters are - can you explain or provide a link?

Comment: What characters? Are you complaining about my handwriting? Or, more accurately, my mousewriting? Or asking for more information about regular expressions? (In the latter case, Google is your friend.)

Comment: Not your handwriting :) the crossword things. If they are called regular expressions then thanks I'll look them up

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it's a programming matching syntax usually abbreviated regex that many programming languages implement. If you want to so it used and abused head on over to PPCG's [regular-expressions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression) tag :)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  YOURBESTANDWI
> SESTREFUGEFROM
> ALLTROUBLESISI
> NYOURSCIENCE -
>  ADA LOVELACE
> ```